# Filtering DataGridView rows in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, user-interface, filter

I have a DataGridView that is displaying a List of objects (not DataSet).
Is there an easy way to set a filter, so the DGV will only display rows that match the filter?

```
IList<T> log = ...;
dgv.DataSource = log;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have LINQ available? If so, one option is:

```
dgv.DataSource = log.Where(x=>x.IsActive && x.Type == 3).ToList();
```

However, new/removed rows won't update the original list (edits to existing rows are fine).

If not LINQ, you can do the same with `List<T>.FindAll`:

```
dgv.DataSource = log.FindAll(delegate (SomeType x) {
    return x.IsActive && x.Type == 3;});
```

There is the `IBindingListView.SupportsFiltering` / `IBindingListView.Filter` pair, but none of the standard lists (including `BindingList<T>`) implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `Log.Where(filter)` That's generally how I filter items in a list bound to a DGV if I don't have control over the generation.